# what happened to stackexchange flair?

Tags: support, flair, combined-flair

It used to be that there was a flair tab on https://stackexchange.com/users/276507/neubert?tab=accounts but now I'm not seeing it. Has it moved or has the idea of SE-wide flair been removed all together?

Comment: I see the tab on my own SE account page, but not yours. Try changing the URL to http://stackexchange.com/users/276507/neubert?tab=flair

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your flair is linked as a tab on your account page:

[image: flair link]

You won't see it if you are not logged in, however; the link is only visible when logged in and looking at your *own* account.

You can reach it directly by changing the `?tab=` query parameter to `?tab=flair` as well; for any account. Your's is [right there](https://stackexchange.com/users/276507/neubert?tab=flair); here's your flair image from that page:

[image: neubert's flair]