# Flair tab of other users is hidden but still accessible

Tags: discussion, flair, network-profile, combined-flair

When looking at our own [Stack Exchange network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current), we can see the following tabs:

- top
- accounts
- reputation
- activity
- favorites
- inbox
- subscriptions
- flair

When looking at the same page of another user (for example [Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9)), the list is the same as above without *inbox* and *flair*.

If I add `?tab=inbox` to the previous URL, I see the [default page](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9?tab=inbox). In fact, I can add any other string ([e.g. `foo_bar`](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9?tab=foo_bar)) and the page will be the same.

But it's different with `?tab=flair`, it display the [flair tab of the user](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9?tab=flair) but no tab is active in the tabs bar.

Why is this tab accessible if it's hidden?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228920/what-happened-to-stackexchange-flair

Comment: Shouldn't it be? You *usually* don't need to look up someone else's flair, but it is not private information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone's inbox is private information, but someones flair is not.

However, there is little point in showing the flair tab on other accounts, as it is meant for you to post on *other* sites. We can already see how your account is doing without seeing your flair image.

As such, it is public information, but not shown to avoid cluttering up the UI.

Comment: I agree with you. Do you think this hidden page should be removed? It's not easy to discover and I don't see how getting the code to use the flair of someone else is relevant.

Comment: Why would it need to be *removed*? If you are the profile owner, all that changes is that the tab is visible.

Comment: *Why would it need to be removed?* I'm thinking about *dead code*. Somewhere in the code of SE this page is defined, maybe the team of SE is interested in deleting pointless pages.

Comment: *It is not dead code*. It is one view that is **used on your own profile**. The fact that it is accessible on *other* profiles is a nice extra for when we help out debug flair problems.

Comment: What makes you think different code is used when you view the flair on another user's profile versus viewing the flair on your own?

Comment: The fact that the tab is hidden. But I understand your arguments and I'm gonna stop overthinking about this very small part of SE. Thanks for your answer and comments.

Comment: As an aside, I doubt the inbox is private. (At least the public responses in [yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/140890/responses) and [mine](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/84237/responses) can be seen by anyone.)

Comment: @Arjan: interesting; because the AJAX route for the responses gives a 404 unless it is your own. I cannot see [your responses tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/ajax/users/tab/84237?tab=responses&sort=all), but I *can* [see mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/ajax/users/tab/140890?tab=responses&sort=all). Perhaps the feed has certain truely private responses (such as moderator messages) filtered out?