# Add a link to other users' flairs

Tags: feature-request, network-profile, flair

On your own [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=flair), there's a tab to access your combined flair:

[image: my network profile's flair]

I was curious how another user's flair would look like. Some include it in their profile, but if they don't, I can't find a link to it. Is this on purpose?

Note that it's possible (also mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234061/295232)) to change the URL to go to the 'flair' tab: https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9?tab=flair

[image: Shog9's network profile's flair]

but the text is rather odd if it's not your own profile you're looking at (which makes sense, for a non-publicly-linked page).